# asp mvc custom validation how to get other values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, mvvm, data-annotations

I am comparing a username using a custom validation. I am checking if it's the same as the old value or if it passes the regex it is acceptable but if it is not then throw an error. How do i get the UserID from the viewmodel if possible?

```
    [EmailValidation]
    public string Username{ get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }



public class EmailValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
         protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
         {

             User user= User.getUserByID(UserID); //How to get UserID?
             string username= value.ToString();
             if (user.Username== username || IsValid(username))
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("Error");
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get UserID from `ObjectInstance` of [ValidationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.objectinstance.aspx). In your case it will be instance of your User class.

```
public class EmailValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
     protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
         UserDto dto = (UserDto)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
         User user= User.getUserByID(dto.UserID);
         string username = value.ToString();
         if (user.Username == username || IsValid(username))
         {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
         }
         else
         {
            return new ValidationResult("Error");
         }

    }
}
```

If you want something more universal you can add property that specify property name and use reflection to get the value.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick but for some reason it goes through the controller and saves my object instead of blocking the POST request with the valdiation. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have checking ModelState.IsValid in your action?

Comment: I did not that was the problem. Thanks a lot buddy! marked as answer

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to move your validation to the class instead of being a field validator.

For reference: http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2009/10/16/validator.aspx

```
class MyClass : IValidatableObject {
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
      User user= User.getUserByID(UserID); // UserID is available because this is a method on the object
      string username= value.ToString();
      if (user.Username== username || IsValid(username)) {
          // it's fine?
      } else {
          yield return new ValidationResult("Error");
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a 2 step process here so that you may use this attribute in the future with any new classes that come up:

1) Create an abstract class that contains the UserID in it, and have any classes that have this EmailValidationAttribute extend that class.

2) In your validation you can cast `value` to the abstract class type, and just grab the UserID from there.